# LDAP query for `name` works, but returns zero results for `managedBy`

Tags: ldap, ldap-query

I am having trouble performing a query in the LDAP system. Because I am able to query for a manager and receive the list of direct reports, I know the connection is correct.

I would like to search from the `RootDSE` for any item with a partial match in the `managedBy` field. Using `*` as wildcard, I want to search for `*XX9XXX9*`.

I receive the correct record when I perform the following search on the `name` field: `(&(objectCategory=*)(name=XX9XXX99X99X9))`

The `managedBy` field contains the following attributes:

```
CN=Lastname\, Firstname XX9XXX9
OU=Tiered Services
OU=Premium
OU=NCG
OU=Accounts
OU=BAND
DC=corp
DC=XXXXXXXXX
DC=com
```

When I attempt the same query as I did with the `name` field, no results are returned. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to try an alternate method to get what you're after: [managedBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676857%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) contains a distinguished name, and [DNs do not support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684431%28VS.85%29.aspx) the wildcard character in queries.

**Edit:** possible duplicate of [Active Directory C# using ManagedBy attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983135/active-directory-c-sharp-using-managedby-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

Found out the issue that was causing the problem...   the application i /was/ using was not doing the search in the correct manner - it was trying to do a string search, but in reality, the OU entry was not a string, it was a number (ID to the OU)....  the application was trying to think for me.

Instead of showing the ID, it was performing a lookup by itself and presenting the results of the lookup, not the real value in the field.